# Trouble while using AsyncTask to parse xml from sd card

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, parsing, android-asynctask

I have some problem with AsyncTask in my application.
There is AsyncTask which takes File from sd card and makes operations with it.

It is actually giving me a proper result, but while doing the task there are a black screen and a blocked user interface about 3 seconds that obviously would make a user annoyed. I'm wondering how to get rid of this problem.
So here is the code:

**ParseXMLTask.java:**

```
public ParseXMLTask(Context context, IPostParse iPostParse, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.context = context;
    this.iPostParse = iPostParse;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;

}

@Override
protected Intent doInBackground(File... params) {

    File file = params[0];

    Intent pack = new Intent(context, PackActivity.class);

    /* some heavy parsing task */

    return pack;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Intent result) {
    iPostParse.postParse(result);
}
```

**LoadingActivity.java:**

The executing task code:

```
private void parseXML() {
    File file = new File(PATH + fileName + ".xml");

    ParseXMLTask parseTask = new ParseXMLTask(this, this, loadingBar);
    parseTask.execute(file);
}
```

And the implemented method of the interface, nothing special:

```
public void postParse(Intent result) {
    result.putExtra("name", packName);
    result.putExtra("author", packAuthor);
    result.putExtra("date", packDate);
    result.putExtra("file", fileName);
    result.putExtra("votes", votes);
    startActivity(result);      
}
```

Hope you help me to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: use a intent service instead of asynctask

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are putting too much data into your Intent's extras.